Is it possible to share folder to S3 Bucket using Fluent-Bit?
I have log folders which contains different type of log files in it.
My use case:
I want to upload log files to an S3 bucket using fluent-bit, ensuring that each log file is saved with its original filename.
Problem:
All the logs are being consolidated into a single file instead of being separated into individual files in the S3 bucket.
Here is my fluent-bit.conf file. Please suggest some changes to achieve the desired output.
[INPUT]
Name              tail
Path              /mnt/Server_Logs/*.log
Read_from_Head    true
Path_Key          filename
Refresh_Interval  5
Tag               *.logs

[OUTPUT]
Name                           s3
Match                          *.logs
region                         ap-south-1
use_put_object                 On
total_file_size                10M
upload_timeout                 10m
preserve_data_ordering         true
store_dir                      /tmp/fluent-bit/s3
bucket                         bitbucket
static_file_path               On
s3_key_format                  /fluent-bit-logs/$TAG/$filename

Also suggest some improvements in this file if any.

Why not using CloudWatch instead?

Because I have been assigned to explore this.

The issue got resolved by replacing the below line:
s3_key_format                  /fluent-bit-logs/$TAG[5]
At $TAG[5] I have the name of logfile. After this I was getting the required structured logs in my S3 Bucket.
Also I removed the below line because it is of no use.
Path_Key          filename
